# Cocoapods error during pod update

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, dependencies, cocoapods

I've been using Cocoapods without any problems on my projects for a while now, but today I suddenly got this error while trying to update my pods on a particular project:

> [!] Pod::Executable pull
>
> Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master'
>
> from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

I have been trying to work out what is causing this issue but to no avail (it happens on all projects that use Cocoapods during the "Analyzing dependencies" stage).

Does anyone know what's causing this (and how to resolve it)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the git repository that all of CocoaPod's specs come from. It lives in `~/.cocoapods`. To fix issues like this the easiest way is to just delete it entirely with `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` and set it up again with `pod setup`

EDIT:

Today (1/30/14) there was an issue with the specs repo that may make you want to fix this. Read more about it on the [CocoaPods Blog](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/)

Comment: Thanks Keith, that put me on the right track - it made me realise I had tried to add an additional pod spec repo for internal / private libraries. Something had clearly gone wrong there. Thanks for getting me back on track!

Comment: Thank you Keith, this really saved me a log of time!